# Azure: How to synchronize log files without overwriting old ones?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, log4net, azure-blob-storage

I have an issue about synchronizing a log file to the blob storage. Actually, I can synchronize a log file to the blob storage, but after that when I make a new deployment of my project to the azure my project files are changing and the log files' contents changing too, although the file name stays same. Thus WebRole is trying to synchronize the log file and does it, however because of the file name, file is overwriting and all the data in the blob storage has gone. How can I hold log files for different deployments? I hope I can explain you, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the fileName before going to use it. By overriding the File property you can add any unique prefix (DeploymentID,TimeTicks,GUID...) to the file name.

```
   public class AzureLocalStorageAppender:RollingFileAppender
        {
            public override string File
            {
                get
                {
                    //Trace.WriteLine("get_"+base.File);
                    return base.File;
                }
                set
                {
                    base.File = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LocalResourceNameHere").RootPath + @"\"
                        + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                        + new FileInfo(value).Name;
                    //Trace.WriteLine(base.File);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: But if I have change the file name there will be millions of log files because I am synchronizing it minute by minute ?

Comment: Then you can use DeploymentID as prefix. Random Unique value dont suite you.

Comment: Can you give an example how can I use the DeploymentID?

Comment: using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
...
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id

Comment: thanks Nava I have one more question: I am taking the deployment ID and send in a logName parameter to the log4net, but it doesnt create log file.                                                                      log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = @"Logs\projectname" + RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId + ".log";

Comment: hope this link will help you...(http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2011/08/03/using-log4net-in-azure-compute/)